# JavaScript find X,Y of inline element to set popup box next to it

Tags: javascript, location, inline

I have table with few records and I need to show a popup box when the user mouses over a certain record.

I have created the popup box and set the message there. The only thing that's left is to set the coordinates of that box (`<div id="popup"></div>`) so that it's next to the element that triggers this box.

So I got the `this` of the tag I mouse over. Now how can I get its location on the window?

I tried `this.offsetLeft` and it's relative to parent. The element is inline so I don't know how to find it.

I using pure JavaScript and please don't suggest jQuery as I don't want to use it in this project.

Comment: its really, really hard not to suggest jQuery here... is there a particular reason you dont want it?

Comment: You could instead insert your popup `<div>` next to the element in question, and then give it `position: absolute;`

Comment: Phillip Schmidt, because i dont

Pointy, how i can insert it next to it like you mean inside its tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var box = this.getBoundingClientRect();

alert( "y:" + box.top + "x:"+ box.left );​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hNShL/

To take scrolling into account:

```
var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement,
    scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || html.scrollTop || body.scrollTop || 0,
    scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || html.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft || 0,

    box = this.getBoundingClientRect(),

    top = box.top + scrollTop,
    left = box.left + scrollLeft;

alert( "y:" + top + "x:"+ left );​
```

Comment: That is very neat, I never knew about this method and it seems to have been around for quite a long time.

Comment: Could yo be more detail please i dont understand how this works

Comment: @JohnSmith sure, what part is unclear? Here's some documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect

Comment: It does not work in Internet Explorer 8.

and also need to sum box.top + window.pageYOffset to any box.top because if you scroll window its getting size from top of screen not top of page

Comment: i am checking right now and it does not: **Webpage error details
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Tue, 7 Aug 2012 22:11:38 UTC

Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 102
Char: 4
Code: 0

What i have on like 104 is.**
   `document.getElementById('description').style.left = (element.getBoundingClientRect().left+window.pageXOffset)+element.offsetWidth/2+"px";`

Comment: its like popup with <span title="my description"></span> element so i dont want page scrolling.

Comment: never mind its actually "window.pageYOffset" does not work in internet explorer is way to get scroll size in IE?

Is there way to make `document.getElementById('description').style.left = (element.getBoundingClientRect().left+window.pageXOffset)+element.offsetWidth/2+‌​"px";` work in IE without scrolling page to top?

Scrolling page will totally eliminate purpose of popup.

Answer (score 1):

You could try recursively going through the element's [`offsetParent`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.offsetParent) to get their `offsetLeft` values and add them to the element's own `offsetLeft`.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
function offsetLeftRelativeToPage(element) {
    var offset = element.offsetLeft;
    var offsetParent = element.offsetParent;
    if (offsetParent != null) {
        offset += offsetLeftRelativeToPage(offsetParent);
    }
    return offset;
}

var trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');
var popup = document.getElementById('popup');

trigger.onmouseover = function() {
    var offsetLeft = offsetLeftRelativeToPage(this);
    popup.style.left = offsetLeft;
}
```

JSFiddle demo: [jsfiddle.net/e6vWV/](http://jsfiddle.net/e6vWV/)