# selenium unable to get CORRECT location of anchor in paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

First person to answer this (I don't believe there is an answer) gets a free dinner!

I am trying to locate the coordinates of a link (text) in a paragraph to move the mouse to that link to perform a hardware click (not a javascript click or click via selenium).

```
<p>for full automatic work you need to read about <code>DesiredCapabilities</code> as this: <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510816/how-to-handle-downloading-a-file-in-selenium-webdriver">How to handle downloading a file in selenium webdriver?</a></p>
```

Doesn't matter really, the coordinates returned are always that of the enclosing <p>

Look here: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-to-download-a-file-using-seleniums-webdriver

To see the above code on page, look for the text **How to handle downloading a file in selenium webdriver?**

Inspect it, play around with it, no matter how I try to get at the anchor location, I can't seem to find a way to get to it. It's always the paragraph bounding rectangle.

Inspecting in Firefox it will highlight the text (but how to get to that programmatically?)

Seleniun 'finds' the anchor fine, i've tried by text, xpath, css, all find the same tag, inside the <p> and all return the x,y of the <p>.

I've tried a range to count words and calculate the position, but getting the text returns the text of the anchor, not the enclosing paragraph.

thanks in advance!

Comment: You should include the HTML for this element (with <P>) in your post.  (Or explain why the location is different than the <P> parent..?)  When you say "perform a hardware click" does this mean you're using a robot style class outside of the window?  Have you adjusted for being at the screen level instead of the browser level?  You probably also want to include some code trials that show your "hardware click" method, too.

Comment: Sure, it's nothing special. Yes, i've got the coordinate translations down. This is a case where the actual coordinates of the <a> are not revealed. It always returns the position of the <p>. This is from the above page.

Ultimately I've gone for image matching with an offset because it's location is hidden in the DOM.

Comment: Selenium's element.getLocation() method should return coordinates for that element relative to the document's top left corner.   You should include your code.  There are alternatives if Selenium's method is not working for you.  Javascript has methods as well.

Comment: Sure, here is a quick test I ran using two lines of code 
`Point Aloc = webElement.Location;`
`Point Ploc = webElement.FindElement(By.XPath(selector.SelectorPaths[0].SelectorPath + "/parent::node()")).Location;`

The results: a = 233, 9499 & p = 233, 9498

Comment: `Xpath used: "//*[@id="answer-22926"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/p[2]/a"` is found fine, the issue is as described, no way to get the actual coordinates of the A tag...

Comment: You can execute javascript to get each element's offsetLeft, offsetTop and/or getBoundingClientRect() (bounding is relative to viewport though so scroll amount comes into play) to check if it's any different.  Selenium is probably using those under the hood, though.  The styles set on these things will have an impact... especially relative vs absolute positioning.  So you may need to adjust things according to parent's css settings.

Comment: ...also adjust for inline or block style settings.  I think both <p> and <a> will be inline by default, but if set to display: block, it will affect sibling/parent relationships.  Maybe see this post about getting location of inline elements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854352/javascript-find-x-y-of-inline-element-to-set-popup-box-next-to-it

Comment: OK, while the offsetLeft does return a value (744), the Anchor.X coord returned is 251. Adding 744 to it takes it over the edge of the browser (955) and using 744 stops before the actual link, so i'm still stuck not finding any numbers that add up to the actual link text.

Comment: yeah, the layout rules are complicated... search around a bit... I found a link here that seems promising...  it adjust for scrollLeft and clientLeft all the way up the parent elements chain: https://www.kirupa.com/html5/get_element_position_using_javascript.htm

Comment: other things to consider would be scrollable divs and/or iframes.  You may want to include the markup + styles in your post.  I'm a little surprised that Selenium isn't returning the right coords here, since I thought they used those to perform the click in the center of the element.

Comment: "An element’s in-view center point is the origin position of the rectangle that is the intersection between the element’s first DOMRect of getClientRects() and the initial viewport."    So it sounds like they do use getClientRect() here.  That should be the bounding box of the <a>.  I think the problem is that you use parent::node() which might just be pointing to the bounding rectangle of the <a href... tag.   That also explains why there is 1 pixel difference in the top.

Comment: I think "node()" is the key here... that matches a node of any kind... So not an "element" node, but a "text" node.   The first, webElement.Location gets the bounding rectangle coords of the link.  The 2nd, with the "node()" bit in there gets the text node's... which I guess has a slight smaller bounding rectangle?

Comment: note sure how to use node() here. but i'm curious. when i look at the getClientRects, there are two rectangles and the 'Right' of the second rectangle is 511 which is the start of the anchor tag, but it eludes me how to programmatically determine how to utilize the rectangles correctly in a generic sense...

for now i can kludge this

Comment: btw - i also saw that link to get element positions and, alas, it is not useful in this interesting case

Comment: I think you just remove the ()... just use node... that should be element node.  Still not sure if your locator is targetting that <a> tag though... sounds like it's the <p>... and maybe because of node() it's a subset of <p>... so maybe 3 or 4 nodes in there?  (text, <a>, text in <a>, text)

Comment: I gave up on selenium giving wrong answers for this and went around it using javascript to get the actual coordinates. selenium was just wrong and no way around it. https://vishalsays.wordpress.com/2007/12/21/finding-elements-top-and-left-using-javascript/